# Use Reflection to invoke a public method

Tags: java, android, reflection

I'm writing an API and I ran into an issue with using reflection. What I want to do is call a method from a custom object class and return the value to the spot called. The start of the call occurs in the MainActivity.java

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        ByteMe b = new ByteMe();

        ExampleObject object = new ExampleObject("Bob", 20, "indy", "male", "its bobby");
        try {
            b.examine(object);
        } catch (NoSuchMethodException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (InvocationTargetException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IllegalAccessException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

My example object class is meant to help make sure this API works

```
public class ExampleObject {

    private String Name;
    private int Age;
    private String Location;
    private String Sex;
    private String Description;

    /**
     * Empty Constructor
     */
    public ExampleObject() {}

    /**
     * Basic constructor with initializing data
     *
     * @param _Name String with the name of the user
     * @param _Age Integer with the age of the user
     * @param _Location String containing the curret city and state of the user
     * @param _Sex String Male, Female, Transgender, or Other
     * @param _Description String short blurb about the user
     */
    public ExampleObject(String _Name, int _Age, String _Location, String _Sex, String _Description)
    {
        this.setName(_Name);
        this.setAge(_Age);
        this.setLocation(_Location);
        this.setSex(_Sex);
        this.setDescription(_Description);
    }

    public String getName() {
        return Name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        Name = name;
    }

    public int getAge() {
        return Age;
    }

    public void setAge(int age) {
        Age = age;
    }

    public String getLocation() {
        return Location;
    }

    public void setLocation(String location) {
        Location = location;
    }

    public String getSex() {
        return Sex;
    }

    public void setSex(String sex) {
        Sex = sex;
    }

    public String getDescription() {
        return Description;
    }

    public void setDescription(String description) {
        Description = description;
    }
}
```

Now the main issue I have is when I make this call within another file called ByteMe.java:

```
public void examine(Object obj) throws NoSuchMethodException, InvocationTargetException, IllegalAccessException {

        //Get the list of possible methods held in this object.
        Method[] methods = obj.getClass().getMethods();

        // iterate through them
        for (Method method : methods) {
            Log.d("" + this.getClass().getName(), "--------------------------");
            Log.d("" + this.getClass().getName(), "Method: " + method.getName());
            Log.d("" + this.getClass().getName(), "Return Type: " + method.getReturnType());
            Log.d("" + this.getClass().getName(), "Class: " + method.getClass());
            Log.d("" + this.getClass().getName(), "Declaring Class: " + method.getDeclaringClass());

            if(method.getReturnType().getName().contains("int")) {
                try {
                    Method m = method.getDeclaringClass().getMethod(method.getName(), Integer.TYPE);
                    int temp = (int) m.invoke(null, 0); //first argument is the object to invoke on, ignored if static method
                    Log.d("" + this.getClass().getName(),"temp value: " + temp);
                } catch (NoSuchMethodException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                } catch (InvocationTargetException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                } catch (IllegalAccessException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }

            Log.d("" + this.getClass().getName(), "--------------------------");
        }
    }
```

This is an excerpt of my logcat:

```
11-21 20:08:11.704 18121-18121/productions.widowmaker110.byteme D/Library.ByteMe: --------------------------
11-21 20:08:11.704 18121-18121/productions.widowmaker110.byteme D/Library.ByteMe: Method: equals
11-21 20:08:11.704 18121-18121/productions.widowmaker110.byteme D/Library.ByteMe: Return Type: boolean
11-21 20:08:11.704 18121-18121/productions.widowmaker110.byteme D/Library.ByteMe: Class: class java.lang.reflect.Method
11-21 20:08:11.704 18121-18121/productions.widowmaker110.byteme D/Library.ByteMe: Declaring Class: class java.lang.Object
11-21 20:08:11.704 18121-18121/productions.widowmaker110.byteme D/Library.ByteMe: --------------------------
11-21 20:08:11.704 18121-18121/productions.widowmaker110.byteme D/Library.ByteMe: --------------------------
11-21 20:08:11.704 18121-18121/productions.widowmaker110.byteme D/Library.ByteMe: Method: getAge
11-21 20:08:11.704 18121-18121/productions.widowmaker110.byteme D/Library.ByteMe: Return Type: int
11-21 20:08:11.704 18121-18121/productions.widowmaker110.byteme D/Library.ByteMe: Class: class java.lang.reflect.Method
11-21 20:08:11.704 18121-18121/productions.widowmaker110.byteme D/Library.ByteMe: Declaring Class: class productions.widowmaker110.byteme.ExampleObject
11-21 20:08:11.704 18121-18121/productions.widowmaker110.byteme W/System.err: java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: getAge [int]
11-21 20:08:11.704 18121-18121/productions.widowmaker110.byteme W/System.err:     at java.lang.Class.getMethod(Class.java:664)
11-21 20:08:11.704 18121-18121/productions.widowmaker110.byteme W/System.err:     at java.lang.Class.getMethod(Class.java:643)
11-21 20:08:11.704 18121-18121/productions.widowmaker110.byteme W/System.err:     at Library.ByteMe.examine(ByteMe.java:94)
11-21 20:08:11.704 18121-18121/productions.widowmaker110.byteme W/System.err:     at productions.widowmaker110.byteme.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:21)
11-21 20:08:11.704 18121-18121/productions.widowmaker110.byteme W/System.err:     at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5958)
11-21 20:08:11.704 18121-18121/productions.widowmaker110.byteme W/System.err:     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1129)
11-21 20:08:11.704 18121-18121/productions.widowmaker110.byteme W/System.err:     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2364)
11-21 20:08:11.704 18121-18121/productions.widowmaker110.byteme W/System.err:     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2474)
11-21 20:08:11.704 18121-18121/productions.widowmaker110.byteme W/System.err:     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:144)
11-21 20:08:11.704 18121-18121/productions.widowmaker110.byteme W/System.err:     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1359)
11-21 20:08:11.704 18121-18121/productions.widowmaker110.byteme W/System.err:     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
11-21 20:08:11.704 18121-18121/productions.widowmaker110.byteme W/System.err:     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:155)
11-21 20:08:11.704 18121-18121/productions.widowmaker110.byteme W/System.err:     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5696)
11-21 20:08:11.704 18121-18121/productions.widowmaker110.byteme W/System.err:     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
11-21 20:08:11.704 18121-18121/productions.widowmaker110.byteme W/System.err:     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
11-21 20:08:11.704 18121-18121/productions.widowmaker110.byteme W/System.err:     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1028)
11-21 20:08:11.704 18121-18121/productions.widowmaker110.byteme W/System.err:     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:823)
11-21 20:08:11.704 18121-18121/productions.widowmaker110.byteme D/Library.ByteMe: --------------------------
```

I looked up the NoSuchMethodFound error and most of stackoverflow said it was due to the method being `private` but my method is `public`. The invoke method in examine() should return 20 since thats the age of the object I made in the MainActivity. It just throws an exception though. help?

*EDIT* Alain O'Dea, thanks for the help. this is what i had to change to make it work.

```
 public void examine(Object obj) throws NoSuchMethodException, InvocationTargetException, IllegalAccessException {

        //Get the list of possible methods held in this object.
        Method[] methods = obj.getClass().getMethods();

        // iterate through them
        for (Method method : methods) {
            Log.d("" + this.getClass().getName(), "--------------------------");
            Log.d("" + this.getClass().getName(), "Method: " + method.getName());
            Log.d("" + this.getClass().getName(), "Return Type: " + method.getReturnType());
            Log.d("" + this.getClass().getName(), "Class: " + method.getClass());
            Log.d("" + this.getClass().getName(), "Declaring Class: " + method.getDeclaringClass());

            if(method.getReturnType().getName().contains("int")) {
                try {
                    int temp = (int) method.invoke(obj);
                    Log.d("" + this.getClass().getName(),"temp value: " + temp);
                } catch (InvocationTargetException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                } catch (IllegalAccessException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }

            Log.d("" + this.getClass().getName(), "--------------------------");
        }
    }
```

logcat

```
11-21 20:48:15.459 26949-26949/productions.widowmaker110.byteme D/Library.ByteMe: --------------------------
11-21 20:48:15.469 26949-26949/productions.widowmaker110.byteme D/Library.ByteMe: Method: getAge
11-21 20:48:15.469 26949-26949/productions.widowmaker110.byteme D/Library.ByteMe: Return Type: int
11-21 20:48:15.469 26949-26949/productions.widowmaker110.byteme D/Library.ByteMe: Class: class java.lang.reflect.Method
11-21 20:48:15.469 26949-26949/productions.widowmaker110.byteme D/Library.ByteMe: Declaring Class: class productions.widowmaker110.byteme.ExampleObject
11-21 20:48:15.469 26949-26949/productions.widowmaker110.byteme D/Library.ByteMe: temp value: 20
11-21 20:48:15.469 26949-26949/productions.widowmaker110.byteme D/Library.ByteMe: --------------------------
```

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis getting the value from the object class in the line `Method m = method.getDeclaringClass().getMethod(method.getName(), Integer.TYPE);
                    int temp = (int) m.invoke(null, 0); //first argument is the object to invoke on, ignored if static method
                    Log.d("" + this.getClass().getName(),"temp value: " + temp);`

Comment: I don't know what you're trying to say. Your exception occurs because you're looking for a method called `get` that takes an `int` argument. You have no such method.

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis I don;t understand that I'm looking for a method `get` when the logcat throws the exception when trying to process the method `getAge`. that method returns an int

Comment: `java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: getAge [int]` and `.getMethod(method.getName(), Integer.TYPE);` Why the `int` paramter?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have this code:

```
int temp = (int) m.invoke(null, 0); //first argument is the object to invoke on, ignored if static method
```

And you get this stack trace as a result:

```
11-21 20:08:11.704 18121-18121/productions.widowmaker110.byteme W/System.err: java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: getAge [int]
11-21 20:08:11.704 18121-18121/productions.widowmaker110.byteme W/System.err:     at java.lang.Class.getMethod(Class.java:664)
11-21 20:08:11.704 18121-18121/productions.widowmaker110.byteme W/System.err:     at java.lang.Class.getMethod(Class.java:643)
11-21 20:08:11.704 18121-18121/productions.widowmaker110.byteme W/System.err:     at Library.ByteMe.examine(ByteMe.java:94)
11-21 20:08:11.704 18121-18121/productions.widowmaker110.byteme W/System.err:     at productions.widowmaker110.byteme.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:21)
11-21 20:08:11.704 18121-18121/productions.widowmaker110.byteme W/System.err:     at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5958)
11-21 20:08:11.704 18121-18121/productions.widowmaker110.byteme W/System.err:     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1129)
11-21 20:08:11.704 18121-18121/productions.widowmaker110.byteme W/System.err:     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2364)
11-21 20:08:11.704 18121-18121/productions.widowmaker110.byteme W/System.err:     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2474)
11-21 20:08:11.704 18121-18121/productions.widowmaker110.byteme W/System.err:     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:144)
11-21 20:08:11.704 18121-18121/productions.widowmaker110.byteme W/System.err:     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1359)
11-21 20:08:11.704 18121-18121/productions.widowmaker110.byteme W/System.err:     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
11-21 20:08:11.704 18121-18121/productions.widowmaker110.byteme W/System.err:     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:155)
11-21 20:08:11.704 18121-18121/productions.widowmaker110.byteme W/System.err:     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5696)
11-21 20:08:11.704 18121-18121/productions.widowmaker110.byteme W/System.err:     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
11-21 20:08:11.704 18121-18121/productions.widowmaker110.byteme W/System.err:     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
11-21 20:08:11.704 18121-18121/productions.widowmaker110.byteme W/System.err:     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1028)
11-21 20:08:11.704 18121-18121/productions.widowmaker110.byteme W/System.err:     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:823)
11-21 20:08:11.704 18121-18121/productions.widowmaker110.byteme D/Library.ByteMe: --------------------------
```

Notably **getAge(int)** is a non-static (instance) method:

```
public int getAge() {
    return Age;
}
```

The problem triggering that exception stems from this code:

```
Method m = method.getDeclaringClass().getMethod(method.getName(), Integer.TYPE);
```

That would ask for a method **int methodName** (for example **int getAge(int)**) which doesn't exist triggering the **NoSuchMethodException**.  This is a superflouous step since you can just call **invoke** on **method** instead.

That won't work alone though since the invoke has issues too.  So you have to make the reflective call with the object instead of **null**.  That isn't the full problem either.  The method is **int getAge()** not **int getAge(int)**.  It doesn't take an **int** parameter.  So you also need to remove the **0** parameter from **invoke**.

Here is the corrected line:

```
int temp = (int) method.invoke(obj); //first argument is the object to invoke on, ignored if static method
```

The documentation of **Object Method.invoke(Object,Object...)** is useful for reference:

> ```
> public Object invoke(Object obj,
>             Object... args)
>               throws IllegalAccessException,
>                      IllegalArgumentException,
>                      InvocationTargetException
> ```
>
> Invokes the underlying method represented by this Method object, on
>   the specified object with the specified parameters. Individual
>   parameters are automatically unwrapped to match primitive formal
>   parameters, and both primitive and reference parameters are subject to
>   method invocation conversions as necessary.
>
> If the underlying method is static, then the specified obj argument is
>   ignored. It may be null.
>
> If the number of formal parameters required by the underlying method
>   is 0, the supplied args array may be of length 0 or null.
>
> If the underlying method is an instance method, it is invoked using
>   dynamic method lookup as documented in The Java Language
>   Specification, Second Edition, section 15.12.4.4; in particular,
>   overriding based on the runtime type of the target object will occur.
>
> If the underlying method is static, the class that declared the method
>   is initialized if it has not already been initialized.
>
> If the method completes normally, the value it returns is returned to
>   the caller of invoke; if the value has a primitive type, it is first
>   appropriately wrapped in an object. However, if the value has the type
>   of an array of a primitive type, the elements of the array are not
>   wrapped in objects; in other words, an array of primitive type is
>   returned. If the underlying method return type is void, the invocation
>   returns null.
>
> Parameters:
>
> - obj - the object the underlying method is invoked from
> - args - the arguments used for the method call
>
> Returns:
>
> - the result of dispatching the method represented by this
>     object on obj with parameters args
>
> Throws:
>
> - IllegalAccessException - if this Method object is enforcing
>     Java language access control and the underlying method is
>     inaccessible.
> - IllegalArgumentException - if the method is an
>     instance method and the specified object argument is not an instance
>     of the class or interface declaring the underlying method (or of a
>     subclass or implementor thereof); if the number of actual and formal
>     parameters differ; if an unwrapping conversion for primitive arguments
>     fails; or if, after possible unwrapping, a parameter value cannot be
>     converted to the corresponding formal parameter type by a method
>     invocation conversion.
> - InvocationTargetException - if the
>     underlying method throws an exception.
> - NullPointerException - if
>     the specified object is null and the method is an instance method.
>     ExceptionInInitializerError - if the initialization provoked by this
>     method fails.

SOURCE: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/reflect/Method.html#invoke(java.lang.Object,%20java.lang.Object...)

Comment: I will clarify all of the changes I made but this gave me what I needed to fix the issue

Comment: It's not `invoke` that's the root cause here, it's `getMethod`.

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis `Method[] methods = obj.getClass().getMethods();` how so? That gets all of methods of **obj** and then the code iterates over them looking for all that return **int** and calls them.

Comment: Look at the stack trace and look at `Method m = method.getDeclaringClass().getMethod(method.getName(), Integer.TYPE);`

Comment: While this is an issue, `invoke` doesn't throw `NoSuchMethodException`, so it's not the cause of the error the OP is seeing.

Comment: @rharter I see it now.  Thw question was edited.  The **getMethod** was there and was the problem.  You are correct.

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis thank you for finding that error in my answer.  I believe I have corrected it by adding the discussion of removing **getMethod** before the discussion of correcting **invoke**.

Answer (score 2):

If you look at the [docs](https://developer.android.com/reference/java/lang/Class.html) for the Class class, you'll see that `getMethod(String name, Class...<?> parameterTypes)` takes arguments that denote the method name ("getAge" in your case) and the parameter types (Integer).  The class you're accessing has no method with that signature (`public int getAge(int age)`), hence the NoSuchMethodException. It's not lying to you.

Also, since you already have the methods to step through, why not just call `m.invoke(obj)` if it's the right one instead of querying the class for the method again?  That might clean things up a bit.

Lastly, as your comment says, when you call `invoke()` you need to pass the object that you are invoking the method on, unless it's static (which it isn't).  So you need to change that to `m.invoke(obj)`.

Comment: "The class you're accessing has no method with that signature (public void getAge(int age)), hence the NoSuchMethodException" OP's code make no attempt to call invoke on a method returning **void**.  Please correct that.

Comment: Your answer is otherwise correct so my downvote will become an upvote with that corrected :)

Comment: hah, I see what's happening here.  yes, I wrote my answer for the original question, which included the error being thrown from `getMethod`.  I think adding that to your answer makes it even better than mine.

Comment: you actually found the real issue first and I found a followup issue and originally missed that. Sorry for sharking your accept here.